# Issue with latest maven assembly plugin not coming through to nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

I have a complex project setup. 
in one of my sub-modules i am referencing below plugin without the version.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>       
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Maven then decides that it will try resolve this dependency with version org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:3.0.2

I get the failure that it cannot find it on my Nexus Server?

It resolved alot of my other dependencies but it cannot pull this specific one from central maven (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)?

can anyone please tell me what could be the issue?

---

```
 Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:3.0.2 in http://{nexus-server}:8082/repository/maven-public/
```

Nexus Server OSS 3.3.0-01

Comment: Can I ask why are you hosting `maven-jar-plugin` in your own nexus, when it is publicly available?

Comment: I am not hosting it as per my description (It resolved alot of my other dependencies but it cannot pull this specific one from central maven (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)). This is a proxy repository to maven central where the plugin is available. it is not pulling through to my **proxy**  repository.

Comment: You could enable access logs on your proxy and see what is maven trying to access (what url on central)

Comment: @Andrei, how do i enable that?

Comment: It is setup dependent. I see that Nexus seems to have some sort of UI that could allow this. Other than this, perhaps a conf logback file is in there?

Comment: What are you referring to. you know that i am saying that i create a Proxy Repo that is in Nexus aswell that this is just a remote repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. It was something wrong with the caching.
There is a setting in the repository that was needed to be disabled.

**Negative Cache**
Not found cache enabled:
Cache responses for content not present in the proxied repository

Comment: How you did that :) ?